# why we need to login to Microsoft to be able to use the OneDrive client application

Tags: 2013, administration, onedrive-for-business, onedrive

We have sharepoint on-premises 2013, and i want to be able to sync documents inside the sharepoint document libraries with my PC.
so from this link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OneDrive-desktop-app-for-Windows-850703dd-ea56-4c7a-bff5-6c2e4da227cf i download the OneDrive client application to my Windows 7 PC. when i first open "OneDrive" client application, **i was asked to sign in**.. so i thought i need to provide my domain username and password.. but seems i need to have a Microsoft account to use the OneDrvie .. 
now in our case we have sharepoint on-premises. **so does this mean that each user should have a Microsoft account to use the OneDrive client application ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the OneDrive client for on-premises SharePoint. Instead, you must use the OneDrive for Business client that is shipped as part of Office 2013.

Comment: thanso for the reply ..can you please provide the exact official names for these so i can know exactly which program to use? now the intend for us it to have a client application which allow users to Sync sharepoint documents with their PCs... so they can read/edit the documents even if they are offline.. now i usually use the old application which is "SharePoint workspace" and it is working with sharepoint 2013 on-premises .. but i need to start using OneDrive instead ...

Comment: OneDrive for Business is the name. You can run an add components to Office to install it.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply.. so should it work in a similar way as the old version which is Sharepoint workspace ?? or for our users to  use the OneDrvie for business client application, i need to do extra work on the farm ?

Comment: No additional work on the farm is required once they have the client installed.